# How to receive propertyPath in Hibernate custom message interpolation?

Tags: hibernate, validation, jpa, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

When I implement MessageInterpolator I didn't found the way to recieve propertyPath/propertyName that validation is occuring upon. In some cases I want to prepend propertyName to the error message.

I can, howewever, retrieve it *after* bean validation fails from ConstraintViolation.

```
propertyName = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
```

How can I retrieve this date *before* in message interpolation?

P.S. I saw open issue in Hibernate's JIRA https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-233 So, I gueess that there is no *clean/standard* way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way for doing this, neither portable nor via specific APIs in Hibernate Validator. In Hibernate Validator 5.1 there is [an API](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-701) for making additional objects available  for message interpolation. It might be an idea to expose the property path that way. Could you open a [feature request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV) for this in our JIRA instance?